# Sencha Touch - Add marker to map

Tags: extjs, google-maps-api-3, touch, google-maps-markers

I want to add a marker to a Google map. The problem is that my site is a 'Ext.Container' and not 'Ext.map', because I need a titlebar. This is why getMap() is not working for me. Any chance to get this running?

This is the function that draws the map:

```
    showMapCommand: function() {
    var record = this.getRecord();

    var map = new Ext.Map({
        title: 'Map',
        useCurrentLocation: false,
        mapOptions: {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(record.data.latitude, record.data.longitude),
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            rotateControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            controlPosition: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            zoom: 15,
            keyboardShortcuts: false,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(record.data.latitude, record.data.longitude),
        icon: 'resources/images/marker.png'
    });

    this.add([
        map
    ]);
},
```

The error message of the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
    map: map.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(record.data.latitude, record.data.longitude),
    icon: 'resources/images/marker.png'
});
```

hope it helps-

**Edit**:

Why dont you create a separate file with Ext.defining your map, and you just add it as an item of your container. That way you could `this.getMap()`

Comment: Now I don't get a error message, but there is still no marker.

Comment: Why dont you create a separate file with Ext.defining your map, and you just add it as an item of your container. That way you could this.getMap()